# Unable to ping inside or outside network with default gateway 0.0.0.0

Tags: ethernet, gateway

I've been around here before and I could usually piece together everything to more or less get myself up and running, but this time I'm truly stumped.

I'm trying to connect my new 14.04 install to a network, and I'm forced to be behind my college's router. Now I've tested the vary cable that is right now plugged into my Ubuntu box on a Windows, Mac OS X, and even my friend's Ubuntu 14.04 box, and they all connect no problem. I've been trying to track this down for about two days, but every time I get close to it, the bug jumps to some other piece of my connection.

Anyway, as it sits `ifconfig -a` gives:

```
eth2    Lninkencap:Ethernet  HWaddr:00:1f:bc:08:31:1d
        inet addr:10.32.51.51 Bcast:10.32.51.155 Mask: 255.255.255.0
        UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
        RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
        TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
        RX bytes:0 TX bytes:0
```

as well as the local loopback, but I'm assuming that is not an issue here.

`sudo dhclient -v eth2` returns:

```
Listening on LPF/<hardware address of my integrated NIC, above>
Sending on <same>
Sending on Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST of 10.32.51.51 on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6f4a66ba)
<two more lines of same>
DHCPDISCOVER on eth2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x156f9fb4)
<many more of above with varying intervals>
No DHCPOFFERS received.
Trying recorded lease 10.32.51.51
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
bound: renewal in <large number> seconds
```

If I then try `ping 8.8.8.8`, I get:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

/etc/resolv.conf only contains the two lines telling you not to edit it, while /etc/network/interfaces only has the loopback interface block in it. I've tried commenting out the "option rfc3442" line in /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf which seemed to fix this issue for many people, as well as adding the line

```
send vendor-class-indentifier "MSFT5.0"
```

to dhclient.conf as well to tell the router I'm a windows box, in case they don't like Linux.

Finally, `route -n` reveals:

```
Destination     Gateway     Genmask           Flags     Metric    Ref     Use     Iface
10.32.51.0      0.0.0.0     255.255.255.0     U         0         0       0       eth2
```

I would like to apologize in advance for the doubtless butchered text alignment, but I'm obviously typing this all by hand, reading from the terminal as I type commands. I'm hoping this is an interesting problem, and not something I blithely stumbled past in my (apparent) over-confidence.

TIA!

Quick addendum before posting: The activity light on the ethernet port are lit and one blinks during boot, but they rarely (and seemingly randomly) do so afterwards (both are dark) even while running dhclient in the foreground. When I had the Ubuntu box tethered to my MacBook earlier, I got what looked like a normal power/uplink blinking pattern, but was unable to ping one from the other.

Comment: The fact that your computer receives no DHCP offers suggests that you college's network administrator has a MAC whitelist policy - you may need to ask them to add your ethernet interface's MAC to the whitelist.

Comment: I thought that too, but my MacBook connects through the very same port I've been trying to use no problem, but the Ubuntu box won't connect even through one of the ports in my dorm where my friend (also running Ubuntu 14.04) connects no problem

Comment: The MAC address is a property of your specific computer - not of the router port you're plugging it into

Comment: Exactly. Because the network is playing nice with the school's Windows box, my personal mac, and a different Ubuntu machine, I'm assuming the MAC isn't an issue; neither of the last two machines have any more reason to be whitelisted than my non-working one.

Comment: Turned out to be faulty hardware

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was a hardware issue- there's a known manufacturing defect in the ethernet controller. EVGA x58 micro, if you were curious.